# How get the status of Google apps services?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new and I hope that my experience with StakOverflow will be a success.

Currently I am trying to do me a big dashboard and I'd like to also get the status of Google apps services that found on this page "http://www.google.com/appsstatus"

But I don't know how to get the status of the services. I just need to have the current state (with a verification on every minute), no need for history.

Does anyone can help me or any idea how I can do that ?
I would do with javascript and HTML

Thank you in advance for all your help
(Sorry for my english)

Sincerly,
Daniel

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you should implement this on the server side because of browser's security restrictions (you won't be able to fetch information by cross-domain request). This is a common issue on StackOverflow. Try search `Cross-Domain`.

Once you pass HTML of http://www.google.com/appsstatus from the server to the client you can use jQuery/DOM methods to extract the table with statuses. Like this code does:

```
var icons = $(".aad-body.aad-icon"); // gets all status icons of services
var services = $(".aad-body.aad-service"); // gets all services names

// example for first service
var isGreen = $(icons[0]).children(":first").hasClass("aad-green-circle");
var serviceName = $(services[0]).text();
```

---

With kind regards,
Michael.

Comment: Ouch, it gets a little too complicated for me. Does anyone have an example of how to do this ? Because I'm not sure to understand everything :( Thanks in advance for your help & Thank you Michael for your lights. Rgds, Daniel

Comment: Hi, Again me... ;) You know if you can do that easily with Jquery ? Thank you in advance for your reply. Rgds, Daniel

Comment: Hi! JQuery cannot provide [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Try [this](http://enable-cors.org/).